# How to find a path with limited depth in graph?

Tags: prolog

```
link(a, b).
link(a, c).
link(b, c).
link(b, e).
link(c, f).
link(c, g).
link(c, d).

symlink(F1, F2) :-
  link(F1, F2).

symlink(F1, F2) :-
  link(F2, F1).

profile(a,box). %Tag it is the same as box for a.

find(Start, Tag, Rpath) :
  find2(Start, Tag, 0, [], Rpath).

find2(Step, Tag, Count, Path, Rpath) :-
  C is Count +1,
  C < 5,
  symlink(Step, A),
  compat(A,Tag), % Compatible means the distance between the tag of A
                 % and the Tag that is given as argument should be maximum 1. 
  append(Path, [A|E],Rpath), %This part i want make my final path in Rpath.
  not(member(Step,Path)),
  find2(A, Tag, C, [Step|Path], Rpath).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close to a working predicate here. I've include a code snippet that hopefully solves a few of the small mistakes you make. Notice that `find/3` is the predicate you would actually use (from the outside), a so-called **wrapper clause**.

`find/4` works in the following way:

- The first clause is only used to detect a transgression of the maximum depth.
- The second clause is only used to detect a goal node, i.e. one that matches the given tag.
- The third clause does the real job of finding a symmetric link in the graph.

Some small things to note:

- Renamed `symlink/2` to `symmetric_link/2` to avoid confusion with symbolic links.
- Used `\+` instead of `not` for negation (the former is more common I believe).
- Used `tag/2` for tagging nodes, not `profile/2` to avoid confusion with the act of profiling/analyzing code performance.

Code snippet:

```
link(a, b).
link(a, c).
link(b, c).
link(b, d).
link(b, e).
link(c, f).
link(c, g).
link(c, d).

tag(a, box).

symmetric_link(F1, F2) :-
  link(F1, F2).
symmetric_link(F1, F2) :-
  link(F2, F1).

maximum_depth(5).

find(Start, End, Path):-
  find(Start, End, 0, [Start], Path).

find(_, _, Depth, _, _):-
  maximum_depth(Max),
  Depth > Max, !,
  fail.
find(Node, Tag, _, _, [Node]):-
  tag(Node, Tag), !.
find(Node1, Tag, Depth1, History, [Node1|Path]):-
  symmetric_link(Node1, Node2),
  \+ memberchk(Node2, History),
  Depth2 is Depth1 + 1,
  find(Node2, Tag, Depth2, [Node2|History], Path).
```

Example of usage:

```
?- find(g, box, Path).
Path = [g, c, d, b, a] ;
Path = [g, c, a] ;
Path = [g, c, b, a].
```

I have not fully tested this predicate and would advice you to write a unit test for these kinds of predicates. I use [plUnit](http://swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/plunit.html%27%29) for this, which runs on SWI-Prolog and SICStus Prolog, but there may be others as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes that works good ,all I want to know: if we have different verification (as my example) should i write clause foe each condition or I can do it in one or max two clauses? and your cod helped me a lot .

Comment: What's "different verification"? Can you give an example?

Comment: like these :memberchk(Node2, History),  Depth > Max,  compat(A,Tag)>>>Compatible means the distance between the tag of A
 and the Tag that is given as argument should be maximum 1.

Comment: @user258403 My code does the depth check in clause 1. The history check is done in clause 3. The compatibility check you are asking about does not occur in my code, but I would call this a **goal condition**, i.e. checking whether a given node is a goal node or not. The current goal condition is `tag(Node, Tag)`. This is where you would have to introduce your own goal condition / compatibiity check.